# TensorFlow typechecking error in ludwig training

Tags: python, tensorflow, window, ludwig

I am getting this issue in Ludwig training from TensorFlow.

```
C:\Users\FRT\Desktop\workspace\pipeline-builder-ide\python\python37\lib\site- 
 packages\typeguard__init.py:906: UserWarning: no type annotations present -- not 
typechecking tensorflow_addons.layers.max_unpooling_2d.MaxUnpooling2D.init__ warn('no type 
annotations present -- not typechecking {}'.format(function_name(func)))
```

The Ludwig model is trained but I want to hide this warning. I have tried

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
warnings.warn = warn
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')
logging.getLogger('ludwig').disabled = True
logging.getLogger('typeguard').disabled = True
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

I have tried all these solutions one by one with no luck. The warning is still printed. How can I hide that warning, and why is this warning occurring?